# MikTex doesn't install tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex2.9

I installed MikTex on my PC.

Now I want to create a document.
Always if I want to include tikz I get the following Error:

> File `tikz.sty' not found. \author

But MikTex didn't tried to install tikz.
Because of that I tried to install tikz with the console manually.

MikTex says it worked. But If I trie to compile the document the same error apears. So I searched in my filesystem. But I can't find tikz.

There is the same problem If I want to use pgfplot.

Why does MikTex doesn't install pgf and tikz anymore?
And how to solve this problem?

Comment: duplicate of [pgf/tikz no longer works after update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468953/138900)

Comment: Try update the database in miktex.

Comment: Oh thank you AndréC I hadn't seen that sorry for the duplicate. I can't close this question by my selfe. Maybe someone else is able to do that.

Comment: @Ahrtaler You can delete that by clicking the "delete" button.